Flutter, 3.22.2, Duplicate class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver found in modules jetified-firebase-iid
Originally, the project of flutter version was 3.16.9
Currently I have to use latest version of Flutter which is 3.22.2
And I did also upgrade firebase versions in pubspec.yaml
(Because of the new Flutter Version)
cloud_firestore: ^5.0.1
firebase_storage: ^12.0.1
firebase_auth: ^5.1.0
firebase_core: ^3.1.0
firebase_messaging: ^15.0.1

and when I do flutter pub get, it works fine
but when I run this project, it shows error
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-20.3.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.3.0) and jetified-firebase-messaging-24.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:24.0.0)



 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


In build.gradle (app):
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"


You saved my life. How did you know this? What did you refer to? teach me
